# How many $k+1$ dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_q^n$ contain a $k$ dimensional subspace $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces

Given a $k$-dimensional subspace $S$ of $\Bbb{F}_q^n$ ($n$-dimensional vector space over finite field of $q$ elements), I want to know how many $k+1$ dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_q^n$ contain $S$. My initial approach was that given a basis of $S$, any vector in $\Bbb{F}_q^n$ not contained in $S$ will be linearly independent to that basis, so you can add that vector to the basis to produce a $k+1$ dimensional subspace contained in $S$. $\Bbb{F}_q^n$ has $q^n$ elements and $S$ has $q^k$ elements so that would mean there are $q^n-q^k$ vectors that you can add to give you a $k+1$ dimensional space. For each of these vectors, all scalar multiples excluding zero will give you the same $k+1$ dimensional subspace when added to the basis so we need to divide by $q-1$. Therefore there are $(q^n-q^k)/(q-1)$ of these $k+1$ dimensional subspaces in $\Bbb{F}_q^n$ containing $S$. My issue is that I saw somewhere that the answer is in fact  $(q^{(n-k)}-1)/(q-1)$ which is clearly different to what I've found, so I was wondering where I went wrong.

Any help is appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more possible vectors that give the same subspace.

Which are they?

Well, once you have selected the subspace, notice that this subspace has size $q^{k+1}$, so there are actually $q^{k+1}-q^k$ vectors that give the same result.

So the answer is $\frac{q^n - q^k}{q^{k+1}-q^k}$